# How to get the HTTP_REFERER from a Yahoo or Gmail

Tags: php, http-referer

I have an e-mailer script that send messages to Yahoo or Gmail with a link on it, a link that will return back to my website when it is clicked.

I need to get the HTTP_REFERER from Yahoo or Gmail. in my site I have

> echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

expecting something to return on it. but its empty.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be by design. It is possible to remove the header using Javascript shenanigans. From [Google's docs on GMail privacy](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/about_privacy.html):

> Minimized "referrer" header information. When you click on links in messages, the web browser that loads contains a referrer header. When you click on links in Gmail, Google takes steps to eliminate this referrer header, preventing others from knowing that you clicked on a link from an email.

Answer (score 2):

You have no control over HTTP_REFERER. What you see is what the client passed.

Answer (score 0):

The browser might not provide HTTP_REFERER so you cannot rely on it -
Secondly, some software firewalls (like Norton Internet Security) have
features to strip out such information...