# Email Tracking AOL Webmail/Desktop

Tags: php, email, analytics, aol

I'm trying to continue building up an email tracker - successfully done GMail Yahoo and several web clients. Now I'm stuck with AOL webmail.

Trying the usual methods of using `HTTP_REFERER`, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and `REMOTE_ADDR` have all yeilded in showing my details and nothing for the referer.

Upon further inspection, it seems that AOL's Webmail somehow is loading the messages into an iFrame where the content is local.

Is there anyway to get the referer and still show the image - I did think of using javascript's parent method, though this would stop the tracker pixel/web bug from appearing. Besides, it wouldn't load in web clients.

I would appreciate any help. I also would like to know if AOL's Desktop Email had a User Agent string - I haven't looked on Google just yet (though finding User Agent's for email clients is difficult - still hunting for Outlook versions prior to 2007).

Comment: Is your image on HTTP or HTTPS? If its on HTTP, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052893/email-tracking-gmail/5072513#5072513

Comment: I've tried both HTTP and HTTPS - the tracker does increase by one, but no user agent or referer is added