# Inferred web email application based on User agent

Tags: php, email, email-client

**TL;DR** How can I infer which web email client has been used based on the UA string of a request?

---

I have run into an interesting problem lately. I parse user agent strings to get the operating system and browser|mobile device|etc. So this is not a question about parsing user agents.

My question is how do you infer what web email application has been used to open the email?

To start of here is some data:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17

Browser: Chrome
OS: Windows 7
```

The email address this was sent to was `example@gmail.com` and I accessed the gmail app from.

The UA-string will be for `Chrome`. I realize that I cannot assume that the email address being `@gmail.com` that the email application used was Gmail.

Its fairly easy to get if an email was read on mobile or the desktop platforms because their UA-strings are different. Even though you get you `@gmail.com` emails on `Outlook 2010`, the Email client will still be Outlook 2010 because it has it's own UA-string.

That is just a bit of the background and some assumptions I made.

EDIT: So I have seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052893/email-tracking-gmail) that this can actually be done. Host your tracking image on `HTTPS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are able to know the email client just checking the UA. As you have said, sometimes you can (for example "outlook") but not always.

Maybe you can check at the **"referer"** to see where the request has been sent from.

Comment: Interesting enough the referrer is a very good answer, there are some limitations though, over a normal http:// protocol, the referrer is hidden from the request tracking image, but when the protocol is secure on your image, https:// then the referrer displays quite nicely. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the UA header is sufficient to make a reliable guess as to which software was used to create an email message. Apart from that the message might have been altered inbetween there are clients that do not specify a meaningful UA header.

I'd guess that you are be able to get a more reliable result when to take into account more details of the message. You have to generate something like a fingerprint. So some rule/test based framework might make sense, testing for details typical for certain solutions. Details like the formal structure of multi part messages, order of header entries and the like.