# What referrer hostname do gmail.com, outlook.com, hotmail.com pass?

Tags: outlook, gmail, hostname, referrer

When someone arrives on my site, I want to check whether they came from Gmail, Outlook.com or Hotmail.com.
I installed Fiddler, but I can't find a the referrer hostname anywhere when I come from Gmail.
Is a referrer hostname even passed for these mail clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't pass the URL in the Referer field if it is an `https://` URL, because it might contain private information. From [RFC 2616 section 15.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.3):

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
> HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
> protocol.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure: that also means since Google.com is now running everything over https, we can't even see anymore if someone came from Google.com (unless checking Google Analytics ofcourse)? And I guess the same goes for Facebook which has always been sending traffic via https?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You'll find that a lot of sites are moving to https-only, which means you won't get referers in many cases.

Comment: Check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052893/email-tracking-gmail apparently if you host your site (or images in email) on https then the referer does get passed on

Comment: @MatthewLock Yes, that's what the "(non-secure)" means in the RFC.

Comment: Also, I noticed that IE does not pass URL referrer for any web based email clients using https. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178066

Answer (score 0):

I found that if both the host and the linked to url are over the same protocols it does pass the `HTTP_REFERER`.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.com passes http_referer even if the link is non-secure (http).  Looks like they just pass "https://outlook.live.com/" as the referer for all requests, which is great. I wish all the major providers would do this.