# How to protect my php script from being called from other domains?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have some php scripts in 2 websites and i want to restrict them to be called only from within those websites. Is there away to achieve this ? Just like some websites disable hot linking and sends user to page that hot linking is not allowed in this site ...

Comment: You could use .htaccess

Comment: Are you seeking information on referrer checking?

Comment: depends how they are being 'called' if only used in other script place them below the web root.

Comment: are these pages only used in include\require? also referrer checking checking is pointless its browser set. if they are web pages public assessable you need to add proper user controls login\password

Comment: Thanks all for reply . how i can do that via .htaccess or referrer checking ? which way is better ? dagon could you explain to me what you mean by " if only used in other script"? for example i have a script dosomething.php?value=14 in main page. I dont want others use this url by calling it from their scripts from their site! I want it to be run from within my domain scripts!

Comment: its on the web, you can protect it like that. you need some proper user management

Comment: sorry can should of been *can't*

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it manually

If(refferer == validHost){
    //allow access
}else{
   //throw exception
}

[Determine I.P. Address of Referring Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224841/determine-i-p-address-of-referring-site)

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is browser set, so easily fakable, many systems strip them altogether for security.

Comment: well he can add some sort of a token, for extra security