# How do i get the url or ip of a requesting page?

Tags: php, xml

I happen to get xml file from http request like this

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I then read and work on this xml file. But the issue is that i need to send an xml http request back to the requesting page... So, how do i get maybe the ip or url of this page to send my request back to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine I.P. Address of Referring Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224841/determine-i-p-address-of-referring-site)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (the referring URL, not always useful... and while "referer" is a misspelling of "referrer", that's how it is because someone typoed it in 1996) and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (the IP address accessing your page).